# how to check value existing in pandas dataframe column value of type list

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas dataframe which contains value in below format. How to filter dataframe which matches the `'d6d4e77e-b8ec-467a-ba06-1c6079aa2d82'` in any of the value of type list part of PathDSC column

i tried

```
def get_projects_belongs_to_root_project(project_df, root_project_id):
        filter_project_df = project_df.query("root_project_id in PathDSC")
```

it didn't work i got empty dataframe

[image]

Comment: i tried filter_project_df = project_df[project_df['PathDSC'].isin([root_project_id])] where root_project_id='d6d4e77e-b8ec-467a-ba06-1c6079aa2d82' it didn't work i got empty dataframe

Comment: You should update that in question

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the values of `PathDSC` column are lists of strings, you can check row-wise if each list contains the wanted value and mask those rows using `Series.apply`. Then select only those rows using boolean indexing.

```
def get_projects_belongs_to_root_project(project_df, root_project_id):
        mask = project_df['PathDSC'].apply(lambda lst: root_project_id in lst)
        filter_project_df = project_df[mask]
        # ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
root_project_id = 'd6d4e77e-b8ec-467a-ba06-1c6079aa2d82'
df = df[df['PathDSC'].str.contains(root_project_id)]
```

Comment: can you check how to do it by passing root_project_id  as part of function parameter? i got KeyError: 'root_project_id'

Comment: df.query accepts a string input and evaluates it as an expression, so simply build the string first and pass it as param to df.query. If your function executing df.query is getting a param named `root_project_id`, then this will work